# Does the solC compiler work in the geth Javascript console anymore

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, solc, console, compiler

does the solC compiler work in the javascript console anymore, and if it does how can I install it. I have tried using the compiler methods in the javascript console api however they do not work and seem to have been deprecated.

I know remix is the best choice to compile my contracts but I would like to use the console if at all possible

Comment: What's the specific error message you're getting that's making you think they're deprecated?

Comment: I have downloaded the solC package and I am trying to link it to my geth, however on the docs it says <code> admin.setSolc("path/to/solc") </code> however when I try this it i get a type error saying that SolC is not a function

Comment: You're right, it seems to have been removed: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14535